# date-time in swagger is getting converted to millis in response

Tags: java, spring, datetime, swagger

I am new to swagger. 
I am trying to expose our contract in swagger. Everything is working as expected, except the dateTime fields. I am specifying something like this in swagger .yaml file -

```
myTime: {
  type: string,
  description: 'My Time.',
  format: date-time
}
```

In swagger editor, the value is absolutely correct - "2020-05-29T04:46:56.028Z".
But when I am firing the api (via postman), the value of myTime is coming in millis.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Post your server code that returns the `myTime` value. What framework do you use - .NET+Swashbuckle, Java+Springfox, Swagger-PHP, ...?

Comment: We are using spring framework, with fasterxml object mapper to parse json containing myTime attribute. The models are generated from swagger .yaml file. Data type of the attibute myTime is org.joda.time.DateTime.

Comment: Hello @Helen 
To parse the json, we are doing something like this : 
`objectMapper.readValue(sampleResponse.getInputStream(), SampleDTO.class);`

As mentioned in my previous comment, we are using fasterxml object mapper as -
`private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;
static  {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
}`